# Peeking in a heap in python

Tags: python, heap, peek

What is the official way of peeking in a python heap as created by the heapq libs? Right now I have

```
def heappeak(heap):
  smallest = heappop(heap)
  heappush(heap, smallest)
  return smallest
```

which is arguably, not very nice. Can I always assume that `heap[0]` is the top of the heap and use that? Or would that assume too much of the underlying implementation?

Comment: Yes you can use heap[0]

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes, you can make this assumption, because it is stated in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/heapq.html):

> Heaps are arrays for which `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]` and `heap[k] <=
>   heap[2*k+2]` for all *k*, counting
>   elements from zero. For the sake of
>   comparison, non-existing elements are
>   considered to be infinite. **The
>   interesting property of a heap is that
>   `heap[0]` is always its smallest
>   element.**

(And that's probably the reason there is no `peek` function: there is no need for it.)

Comment: The reason why I couldn't find this information was probably that I've misspelled peek. Great!

Comment: Though spelling it right would *probably* have helped you, I observe that curiously that word does not occur in the documentation anyway.

Comment: I would take this answer one step further and say that not only is heap[0] the smallest element, but heap[1] is the second smallest element, heap[2] the third smallest, etc

Comment: @BeeGee that's not true, and it doesn't need to be true. You can try out with a simple example yourself.

Comment: +1 As you can see the binary tree, the nodes on same level are not sorted in order they are only lesser or greater than the parent

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Python 2.4 or newer, you can also use heapq.nsmallest().

Comment: Is "n" 1 in this case?

Comment: Be sure to check the complexity of `nsmallest()` you are using. In 3.8 I see e.g. "Make a single pass over the data while keeping the k most extreme values in a heap." ... not ideal for n=1, if you can just `heap[0]`.